# selecting current user with active records in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, select, activerecord, user-data

I have 2 tables **members** and **bank**, **bank** has a foreign key from **members** **(id)**.
the foreign key in **bank** is called **(mem_id)**.

I wish to show all data in **bank** that matches the current users loged in

`session->userdata('id');`

I was thinking, *show * from 'bank' where 'id' from session matches 'mem_id' from bank*

so what I have so far is

```
$query = $this->db->get ("SELECT * FROM 'bank' WHERE 'mem_id' MATCH {$_SESSION['id']}");
    return $query->result();
```

Am I along the right track, or am I going the wrong way about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM bank WHERE mem_id = '".$this->session->userdata('id')."'");
```

You can also use this :

```
$this->db->where('mem_id', $this->session->userdata("id"));
$this->db->get('bank');
```